# How to put image next of input element?

Tags: html, css

I want to put submit.png next to the input element.
This is the code i use:

```html
<div class="input-box" style="height: 40px; width: 500px;">
            <img src="img/delete.png" width="25px" height="25px;" style="position: absolute; right: 0;">
            <input id="answer" type="text" style="border: none; border-bottom: 2px solid silver; height: 100%; width: 100%; font-size: 17px; background-color: #ffffff00; outline: none; color: white; font-weight: bold; text-align: center;" required readonly oninput="let p=this.selectionStart;this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();this.setSelectionRange(p, p);">
            <img src="img/submit.png" width="25px" height="25px">
        </div>
```

I have read other article that said i need to use display: inline-block and float: right attribute.
I have try that and still didn't work.

Please help me

Comment: Put it in spans inside div with clear:both and float:left in css

Comment: @AmitKumarSingh what do you mean by put it in spans inside div?

Comment: span tag inside div @VeriVirgandra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using table and it works like i want

```html
<table style="border-spacing: 30px;">
            <tr>
                <td style="height: 40px; width: 500px;">
                    <img id="backspace" src="img/delete.png" width="25px" height="25px;" style="position: absolute; right: 95px; cursor: pointer;">
                    <input id="answer" type="text" style="border: none; border-bottom: 2px solid silver; height: 100%; width: 100%; font-size: 17px; background-color: #ffffff00; outline: none; color: white; font-weight: bold; text-align: center;" required readonly oninput="let p=this.selectionStart;this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();this.setSelectionRange(p, p);">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <img id="submit" src="img/submit.png" width="35px" height="35px" style="cursor: pointer;">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure if I understood the question but here is a solution with `display: flex`.

```html
<div class="input-box" style="height: 40px; width: 500px; display: flex;">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" width="25px" height="25px;" style="position: absolute; right: 0;">
    <!-- INPUT FIELD -->
    <input id="answer" type="text" style="border: none; border-bottom: 2px solid silver; height: 200px; width: 200px; font-size: 17px; border: 1px solid red; background-color: #ffffff00; outline: none; color: white; font-weight: bold; text-align: center;" required readonly oninput="let p=this.selectionStart;this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();this.setSelectionRange(p, p);">
    <!-- SUBMIT -->
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" width="25px" height="25px">
</div>
```

Let me know if that helps.

Check this nice tutorial about "Flex".
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

you can use css below to put all elements in a div next to each other horizontally:

```
.input-box{
    display: flex;
 }
```

you can also use style below to align them vertically to the center:

```
.input-box{
    align-items:center;
 }
```

Comment: I only want to make the last image in the right of the input-box. If i put display: flex, both image will be in the right of the input box

Comment: no it will keep the order, I tried it my self.
unless some other style makes your input-box width smaller, in that case second image may get displayed under first one.
to see if width is okey you can use inspect tool in firefox > inspector > layout
it will show you border size, margin, padding, width and .etc to find out what brings you image to wrong position

Answer (score 0):

I set the container `display` to `flex` and changed the `order` of the items as per your need and also set the input to cover the available width of the container. Now, you can add margin to the items as necessary. If you have any question feel free to ask.

```css
.input-box{
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.input-box input{
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.input-box img:first-child{
  order: 3;
}

.input-box img:last-child{
  order: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-box" style="height: 40px; width: 500px;">
  <img src="img/delete.png" width="25px" height="25px;">
  <input id="answer" type="text" style="border: none; border-bottom: 2px solid silver; font-size: 17px; background-color: #ffffff00; outline: none; color: white; font-weight: bold; text-align: center;" required readonly oninput="let p=this.selectionStart;this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();this.setSelectionRange(p, p);">
  <img src="img/submit.png" width="25px" height="25px">
</div>
```